# emacs c++ indentation and color highlighting

Tags: emacs, xemacs

I am not getting indentation or colors when I open a cpp/h file with my emacs/xemacs installation on windows. Could you please advise what I need to do in my settings file to make this happen?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `auto-mode-alist` variable that stores the modes that should be invoked in relation with the file extension. This variable is configured by default to associate `c++-mode` to cpp files.

See the content of auto-mode-alist by doing a <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> auto-mode-alist <kbd>RET</kbd>.

You could also try to define the association by yourself like this :

```
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (append '(("\\.\\(CC?\\|HH?\\)\\'" . c++-mode)
        ("\\.[ch]\\(pp\\|xx\\|\\+\\+\\)\\'" . c++-mode)
        ("\\.\\(cc\\|hh\\)\\'" . c++-mode)
        ) auto-mode-alist ))
```

Also note that .h files are by default considered C files, not C++.

Answer (score 0):

Do your files have a `cpp` or `c` extension?

Please have a look at [emacs faq](http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/emacs-21.1/html_chapter/faq_5.html#SEC75)